# Изменение размера блока ссылки

Tags: html

Я создал блок внутри которой ссылка,как изменить размер этого блока,или как правильно засунуть ссылку в блок 
a.new {
background:#ccc;
width:10%:
}

Comment: @aaa, если вам нужно менять размер блока по его содержимому, то тут напрямую сделать ничего нельзя. Однако можно:

* Изменить отступы/размеры самой ссылки внутри блока
* Присваивать таким блокам определенный класс, которым управлять через CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML

```
<div class="block">
    <a href="">Ссылка</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.block{    
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    background: #000;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1em;
}
.block a{
    color: #00f;  
    width: 10%;
    background: #ccc;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0.2em 0.5em;
}
.block a:hover{
    color: #fff;
    background: #000;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mLFn2/